# JavaScript Dialog in Coded UI tests

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I have Coded Ui tests Executing Successfully in IE Browser.

Now I need to test the same with Chrome Browser.

I have Modified the Code as

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";

BrowserWindow.Launch("url", "username", "password");
```

It is Launching URL in Chrome Browser. For User Authentication it is prompting JavaScriptDialog.
How to enter Username, Password in the JavascriptDialog window? 
How to find out the properties of the Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Browser support is limited - see [Comparing automated testing tools](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/tools/1004/comparing-automated-testing-tools-codedui-qtp-selenium)